# jQuery UI Tooltip position on dashicon

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I'm using the build in WordPress built in jQuery UI Tooltip (jquery-ui-tooltip). My problem is controlling the tooltips position on the screen, currently it pops up just above the the help dashicon but it also appear roughly 100px above the icon. The icon itself is in a div that is dynamically aligned to the center. It needs to be fixed in place above the icon and not jump up the page.

The required scripts and styles are added with the following.

```
wp_enqueue_script('wpb-tooltip-jquery', plugins_url('/js/um-tooltip.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery-ui-tooltip'), '', true);
wp_enqueue_style('wpb-tooltip-css', plugins_url('/css/um-tooltip.css', __FILE__), false, null);
wp_enqueue_style( 'dashicons' );
```

um-tooltip.css

```
.ui-tooltip {
    background: #356aa0;
    border: 1px solid white;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font: bold 14px "Helvetica Neue", Sans-Serif;
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px #356aa0;
    max-width:350px;
}
```

um-tooltip.js

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    jQuery('#kaini_pass_info').tooltip({
        content: "'Good' or better on strength meter.<br />" +
            "Password must not be a dictionary word,<br />" +
            "name or keyboard pattern.<br />" +
            "Tips for better passwords :<br />" +
            "Be lengthy (8 or more characters),<br />" +
            "contain uppercase letters (A-Z),<br />" +
            "lowercase letters (a-z), digits (0-9),<br />" +
            "and special characters (&,'^!.\"*[]+- etc)"
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<a id="kaini_pass_info" href="#" title=""><span class="dashicons dashicons-editor-help"></span></a>
```

Comment: this isn't really a WP question...but you should look into absolute positioning for the tooltip instead of relative.  With absolute, you can specify x/y offsets as well.

Comment: Will do, I'll look up absolute positioning, that's probably all I need.

Comment: Do you need that your div don't scroll with the page?

Answer (score 0):

the simple solution to make your tip follow mouse when hover over certain element like so:

```
    $(".selector").tooltip({
        track: true,//make tip follow mouse when hover over all element with class "selector"
        content: "Tooltip content here",

    });
```